# Grouping and transposing data in R

Tags: r, transpose, group

It is hard to explain this without just showing what I have, where I am, and what I need in terms of data structure:
What structure I had:
[image]

Where I have got to with my transformation efforts:
[image]

What I need to end up with:
[image]

Notes:
I've not given actual names for anything as the data is classed as sensitive, but:
Metrics are things that can be measured- for example, the number of permanent or full-time jobs. The number of metrics is larger than presented in the test data (and the example structure above).
Each metric has many years of data (whilst trying to do the code I have restricted myself to just 3 years. The illustration of the structure is based on this test). The number of years captured will change overtime- generally it will increase.
The number of policies will fluctuate, I've just labelled them policy 1, 2 etc for sensitivity reasons and limited the number whilst testing the code. Again, I have limited the number to make it easier to check the outputs.

The source data comes from a workbook of surveys with a tab for each policy. The initial import creates a list of tibbles consisting of a row for each metric, and 4 columns (the metric names, the values for 2024, the values for 2030, and the values for 2035). I converted this to a dataframe, created a vector to be a column header and used cbind() to put this on top to get the "What structure I had" data.
To get to the "Where I have got to with my transformation efforts" version of the table, I removed all the metric columns, created another vector of metrics and used rbind() to put this as the first column.
The idea in my head was to group the data by policy to get a vector for each metric, then transpose this so that the metric became the column, and the grouped data would become the row. Then expand the data to get the metrics repeated for each year. A friend of mine who does coding (but has never used R) has suggested using loops might be a better way forward. Again, I am not sure of the best approach so welcome advice. On Reddit someone suggested using pivot_wider/pivot_longer but this appears to be a summarise tool and I am not trying to summarise the data rather transform its structure.

Any suggestions on approaches or possible tools/functions to use would be gratefully received. I am learning R whilst trying to pull this data together to create a database that can be used for analysis, so, if my approach sounds weird, feel free to suggest alternatives. Thanks

Comment: Please share a reproducible example in R language. Even when your data is huge and/or sensitive  you can post a dummy dataset that represents the same problem and allows us to give an answer you and other users can find helpful. Otherwise you question cannot be answered.

Comment: I agree, ... and from a different perspective, please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: FYI, your last image shows three columns grouped under one heading. R doesn't really do that well, the only ways to do that in a `data.frame` tend to be rather hack-y. The exception being that some report-table-renderers (`stargazer`, `kableExtra`, etc) can do that, but not in a form that allows follow-on data operations (which is why they need to be rendered to that format as the very last step).

Answer (score 0):

First we must to replicate the example simulated data:

```
df <- data.frame(Metric_name=paste("Metric", 1:26),
Policy1 = "2024 value", Policy1 = "2030 value", Policy1 = "2035 value", 
Policy2 = "2024 value", Policy2 = "2030 value", Policy2 = "2035 value", 
Policy18 = "2024 value", Policy18 = "2030 value", Policy18 = "2035 value")
```

Now, define a new data frame shaped about final dimensions:

```
new_df <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:(prod(dim(df[,-1]))), nrow = 3))
```

Now, proceed the replacement as follow:

```
a <- rep(1:78, each=3)
b <- rep(1:3, 78)

for (i in 1:3){
    for (j in 1:78){
    new_df[i,j] <- df[a[j], (i*3-2)+b[j]]
    }
}
```

The final step is to rename columns and rows:

```
rownames(new_df) <- paste("Policy",c(1,2,18))
colnames(new_df) <- paste("Metric", rep(1:26, each=3))
```